Weaker than $X^2 + 1$ conjecture: $(a + bX)^2 + 1$ is a prime number at least once for any $\gcd(a,b) = 1$.
Let $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ where $a, b\in \Bbb{Z}$ and consider $f(X) = X^2 + 1$ and the forward image of the coset $a + b\Bbb{Z}$ under $f$.
There is always at least one prime number in $f(a + b\Bbb{Z})$.
Can we prove this using elementary methods?

If the "$x^2+1$ conjecture" says that there are an infinite number of primes of the form $x^2+1$ then your conjecture implies that one.

In trying to identify counterexamples using the observations in Robert Israel's answer, I find that the range of $X$ influences the outcome. Is $X\in \mathbb Z$ or $X\in \mathbb Z^+$?

Oops: if $a$ is odd and $b$ is even, $(a+bX)^2 + 1$ is even, so can't be prime unless it is $2$.
Similarly, for any prime $p$ such that $-1$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$, you'll have $(a+bX)^2 + 1$ divisible by $p$ when $b$ is divisible by $p$ and $a^2 \equiv -1 \mod p$.
The condition should be that $a^2+1$ and $(a+b)^2+1$ are coprime, not that $a$ and $b$ are coprime.  In that case, your conjecture is a case of Bunyakovsky's conjecture.  But, as mentioned there, this has not been proven for any polynomial of degree $> 1$.  Certainly I wouldn't expect a proof by "elementary methods".
